# How to make a table only visible to a specific user in Django

Tags: python, django

So, I was studying Django and started doing some projects to fixate what I learned.

I'm building a contact book like website and want to make each user have a unique Contacts table.

I've tried putting this on models.py:

```py
class UserContatos(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Contato(models.Model):
        nome = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        sobrenome = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        telefone = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        email = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
        data_criacao = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
        descricao = models.TextField(blank=True)
        categoria = models.ForeignKey(Categoria, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
        mostrar = models.BooleanField(default=True)
        foto = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='fotos/%y/%m/%d')

        def __str__(self):
            return self.nome

    contatos = Contato()


class ContatoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserContatos.Contato
        exclude = ('',)
```

When I use this form to create a contact, it doesn't "go to the user".

Comment: You do not want to make the whole table visible only to one person. What you rather need to do is to add permission in place for users to see content generated by them. All user data will be in the same table but they will see their data only.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking from a different angle. I did that and now it works!!